# Javascript Regex to insert

Tags: javascript, regex

I have functions that I am converting into strings. How would i use regex to insert 'use strict' inside the function.

original.

```
function test() {
    //some code...
}
```

final.

```
function test() {
'use strict';
//some code
}
```

Comment: What possible reason could there be for doing something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
 /(function\s+.*\(\)\s+{)(.*)/
```

Regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hU1eA6/1).

Sample code in Javascript:

```
var re = /(function\s+.*\(\)\s+{)(.*)/;
var str = 'function test() {\n//some code...\n}';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$1\n     \'use strict\';\n$2');
console.log(newstr);
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uga2xnvr/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match

```
(function\s+\w+\(\)\s*\{)
```

and replace with

```
$1\n'use strict';
```

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eU4dX6/1)